# How to get RainLab Blog plugin new post event?

Tags: php, laravel, blogs, octobercms

I use RainLab.Blog plugin on my site running OctoberCMS. I want to send mails to users in my database, whenever I make new post in my blog. I know that I can use `Laravel Notifications` , but can't figure out how to attach it to `new post` event, if there is any.

Comment: https://octobercms.com/plugin/piercetech-pushbulleteer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use model events:
https://octobercms.com/docs/database/model#events

You can use the Extend method on your model E.g: `BlogNews::extend(function { ... })` and either use addDynamicMethod or implement a behaviour that has the event handler methods events you need.